# Exception starting filter struts2 Unable to load configuration : unable to load struts.xml file

Tags: jsp, struts2

I write `struts.xml` file as mention below and run on Eclipse but I get an error.

I also clean Tomcat work directly

**Error is:**

```
Unable to load configuration. - file:/D:/Sonali_workplace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/salesdeals123/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:22:21
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:501)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5473)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - file:/D:/Sonali_workplace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/salesdeals123/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:22:21
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:489)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: Unable to load file:/D:/Sonali_workplace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/salesdeals123/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml - file:/D:/Sonali_workplace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/salesdeals123/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:22:21
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:1022)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadDocuments(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.init(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:132)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:233)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: Element type "action-mappings" must be declared. - file:/D:/Sonali_workplace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/salesdeals123/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:22:21
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:119)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:1017)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/D:/Sonali_workplace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/salesdeals123/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml; lineNumber: 22; columnNumber: 21; Element type "action-mappings" must be declared.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:117)
```

---

**My `struts.xml` file is:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>

<!-- The struts-default package is the Struts 2 default package. 
It defines default result types, interceptors, interceptor stacks, and a few other defaults.. -->

 <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <interceptors>   
            <interceptor name="myCustomInterceptor" class="com.demo.struts.Interceptors.MyCustomInterceptor" />
            <interceptor-stack name="customStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="myCustomInterceptor"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>      
    </package>
    
    
<package namespace="/user" name="default" extends="struts-default">
        
        
        <action name="checkLoginDetail123" class="com.demo.struts.controller.FranchiseLogin_manager">
        <result name="success">/Franchise/FranchiseExecutiveRegistration.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/Franchise/Login.jsp</result>
        </action>
    
    </package>
    
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package"
        value="default" />
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="global" />
    
    
</struts>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is already in your stack trace :)

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId:
>   file:/D:/Sonali_workplace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/salesdeals123/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml;
>   lineNumber: 22; columnNumber: 21; Element type "action-mappings" must
>   be declared.

Answer (score 0):

The file that is a culprit of error is in `WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml`.

> The `struts.xml` configuration file should be in the source folder,
>   such as `src` or `resources`. When you build the application the
>   compiled output directed to `WEB-INF/classes`.
>
> You can check this file
>   exists before you deploy or start a server with already deployed web
>   application.

Comment: to resolve you need to remove `struts.xml` from `WEB-INF/classes` then  clean, rebuild, redeploy your app.

Comment: whenever i clean the project... i got this error. and the solution is to delete the project and again add on eclipse... plz help me...

Comment: You can delete the project many times but it won't help you .